# Question on Fourier-Stieltjes transform (in Rudin, p. $15$)

Tags: proof-explanation, characters, fourier-transform

I have a question on an inequality written on the bottom of [this page](https://books.google.ch/books?id=k3RNtFSBH8gC&pg=PA15&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $\gamma : G \to S^1 \subset \Bbb C$ be a character of $G$.

If $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure on $G$, then we define
$$\widehat \mu (\gamma) = \int_G \gamma(-x)d\mu(x)$$

The inequality that I don't understand is the following :

> $$|\widehat \mu(\gamma_1) - \widehat \mu(\gamma_2)| \leq \int_G |1-(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)(x)| \;d|\mu|(x) $$

For me, it should be
$$|\widehat \mu(\gamma_1) - \widehat \mu(\gamma_2)| \\\stackrel{1}{=}
\left| \int_G \gamma_1(-x) - \gamma_2(-x) \;d\mu(x)  \right|
\\\stackrel{2}{\leq}
\int_G |\gamma_1(-x) - \gamma_2(-x)| \;d|\mu|(x) \\
\\\stackrel{3}{=}
\int_G |(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2)(-x)| \;d|\mu|(x)
\\\stackrel{4}{=}
\int_G |(\gamma_1 - \gamma_2)(y)| \;d|\mu'|(y)$$

where $\mu'(E) = \mu(-E)$.

Where am I wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z,w\in\Bbb C$ and $|z|=|w|=1$ then $|z-w|=|1-z/w|$.

Now, the group operation on the group of characters is pointwise *multiplication*. But it's an abelian group, so the operation is written with a plus sign. Hence the curious-looking fact that $$(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)(x)=\gamma_1(x)/\gamma_2(x).$$

And it gets worse; when he writes $\gamma_1(x)-\gamma_2(x)$ he's talking about actual subtraction. So $$\gamma_1(x)-\gamma_2(x)\ne(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)(x);$$in fact $$|\gamma_1(x)-\gamma_2(x)|=|1-\gamma_1(x)/\gamma_2(x)|=1-(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)(x)|.
$$

This is hideous - when I'm in charge the group operation is written as multiplication even though it's an abelian group....

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you have an idea for my equality $(4)$? For me, we have $\int_G \gamma(-x) \;d\mu(x) = \int_G \gamma(y) \;d\mu'(y)$ where $\mu'(E)=\mu(-E)$, and we may not have $\mu'=\mu$ in general…

Comment: @Alphonse I have no idea what any of the equations you wrote mean. Because you're writing $(\gamma_1-\gamma_2)(x)=\gamma_1(x)-\gamma_2(x)$. That's not true with the unfortunately standard notation, so your notation must mean something else, I can't tell what.

Comment: But in case it helps, $|\gamma(x)|=|\gamma(-x)|$, similarly for various other expressions. Because $\gamma(-x)=1/\gamma(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I've just understood that! Sorry for being unclear in my previous comment. Thank you again :-)